# Mongoose query is very slow (even with lean)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I'm using MongoDB and I handle any modification with Mongoose in Express.
I think the query should be much faster. Correct me if I'm wrong but while this data is big, It isn't that huge. Especially because I'm not filtering or anything during the query.

So the model I use:

```js
const DataSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  text: String,
  text_transform: Array,
  provider: String,
  url: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
  },
  word_count: Array,
  HOW: Array,
  date: Date,
  click_count: Number,
});
```

A few general truths:
**text** size can vary. Can be 150 characters but can also be, let  us say 7000 characters... maybe even more (but generally less than 7000).
**text_transform** is an array whose elements are the words of the *text*.
**provider** is a short string, the maximum I have currently is 12 characters long.
**word_count** is an array that has key-value pairs(arrays) as elements, like so:

```
[
   ["key", value], ["other_key", other_value], ...
]
```

values are numbers, and keys are strings.
**HOW** is an array with a maximum of 5 elements, that are strings. ~6-10 characters.

I have my own API and a request to some endpoint will generally trigger a a query.
My issue comes with trying to retrieve all my data.

So I send a request to this endpoint:

```js
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const data = await DataSchema.find({}).lean();
    res.json(data);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404);
  }
});
```

As you can see, I already use **lean()**, because I'm fine with a simple json.
However, when I do the query on the client side:
[DevTools(F12) - Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygrXH.png)
[xhr request details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVQVe.png)
at this point I had around 270 documents in my database.

I don't think it could be a network issue, because when I limit the query to the first 10 elements, its much faster but still takes a second or so, which is very slow in my opinion.

**Is there any way to make this faster?**

Additionaly you may be interested: For development I am using the free tier of MongoDB Atlas (so no profiler and/or performance analytics), and I'm not yet at production so I have no production environment to test there. Also, the region is Belgium (europe-west1), this is the closest to me, but that shouldn't really make this much difference.

Also, I tried removing **text_transform** as I don't neccessarily need it right now. Not much difference.

**EDIT:**

I forgot to say, I implemented an endpoint that returns a hardcoded json. That is done in less than 1 ms. So that's why I think the query is slow here.

**.explain() results**

```
[
  {
    queryPlanner: {
      plannerVersion: 1,
      namespace: 'test.articles',
      indexFilterSet: false,
      parsedQuery: {},
      winningPlan: [Object],
      rejectedPlans: []
    },
    executionStats: {
      executionSuccess: true,
      nReturned: 301,
      executionTimeMillis: 0,
      totalKeysExamined: 0,
      totalDocsExamined: 301,
      executionStages: [Object],
      allPlansExecution: []
    },
    serverInfo: {
      host: 'some.database-shard.mongodb.net',
      port: 27017,
      version: '4.2.6',
      gitVersion: '20364840b8f1af16917e4c23c1b5f5efd8b352f8'
    },
    ok: 1,
    '$clusterTime': { clusterTime: '6831457389108002820', signature: [Object] },
    operationTime: '6831457389108002820'
  }
]
```

Thank you for taking the time to read, and thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: add `.eplxain()` at the and show us the result pls

Comment: Added it with editing so its in the question for anyone to see immediately @Ifaruki

Comment: well, it says, founded 301 documents in under 1 milli second. i guess the problem is somewhere at your server

Comment: Well, when I do the get request it simply returns the json from the query, I moved the request to my view, to make sure there isn't anything inbetween, it still takes ~30 sec. There are other server side functions, but those shouldn't block this request, otherwise the test endpoint would take  ~30 seconds too. Also I monitor those background processes, and the GET request didn't seem to "wait" for anything.

Comment: also, I just turned off all other functionality (just to be sure) and the query still takes ~30 seconds, I can only think that there might be some issue with MongoDB Atlas?

Comment: well at this point i cant help you, but maybe its atlas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone out there experiencing the same problem. I was suspicious that its MongoDB Atlas, and it is.

The reason, I believe, for the query being slow was that MongoDB Atlas got the request fast, did the query fast but returned the results very slowly. This could've been an overload as its a free M0-sandbox package, using shared servers. I will never know exactly. On the other hand this is quite comforting, as in a production environment something like this should not neccessarily happen.

**TL;DR**

I switched over to a different free mongodb provider for development purposes and everything  loads in an instant.